# Why does my ImageButton not work in AbsoluteLayout? In .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have an ImageButton in a Grid. Around the ImageButton, I have an `<AbsoluteLayout>`. When clicking, nothing happens or the method is not executed.

My XAML:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    BackgroundColor="#24D4A3">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <ImageButton 
                                Clicked="CreateNote"                     
                                Source="add.png"
                                BorderColor="#2b3c3c" 
                                BorderWidth="0" 
                                BackgroundColor="#34A4EB" 
                                CornerRadius="35" 
                                WidthRequest="70" 
                                HeightRequest="70" 
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="313,625" 
                                Padding="2,0,0,0"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </Grid>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

The method CreateNote:

```cs
private async void CreateNote(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//CreateNote");
}
```

I would be grateful for any help!!

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint in the line where the `await` is? Does it get hit when you press the button? Why do you have such a deep nesting of layouts?

Comment: Nope  the method wont be executed :(

Comment: Does it get executed when you remove the `AbsoluteLayout` around it?

Comment: Yes the code will be executed but the button is ofc not on the right place

Comment: Okay, so that means the event handler is attached properly and works. Why are you using a `Margin` to position the button? Normally, you should be using the `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` attached property to position elements in an `AbsoluteLayout`, it might be related to that. Try positioning the button using the attached property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout?view=net-maui-7.0#position-and-size-children

Comment: Okay i tried the AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds. Unfortunately it's still not working :(. nevertheless thx

Comment: And did you remove the margin when you tried with `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds`? Can you show how you tried it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250658/discussion-between-der-illuminate-hd-and-ewerspej).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code to my app and did a test,I found the space above your ImageButton is so large  that I couldn't see it on my emulator.

So I added a `ScrollView` out of the `VerticalStackLayout`.Then I could see the `ImageButton` after I scrolled my page. And I could also trigger the clicked event `ImageButton_Clicked` of `ImageButton` .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1226.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    BackgroundColor="#24D4A3">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                <AbsoluteLayout>
                    <ImageButton 
                                Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"                     
                                Source="icon.png"
                                BorderColor="#2b3c3c" 
                                BorderWidth="0" 
                                BackgroundColor="#34A4EB" 
                                CornerRadius="35" 
                                WidthRequest="70" 
                                HeightRequest="70" 
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="313,625" 
                                Padding="2,0,0,0"/>
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </Grid>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Function `ImageButton_Clicked`

```
private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" click this ImageButton ");
      }
```